# global Actions - recurring tasks

Tags: tasks, global-actions, task-recurrence

Is it possible to use Global Actions to create a recurring task?

Scenario:
want user to click on button in chatter feed on a record, want the user to have option to select "create recurring task" when filling in the record.

Answer (score 2):

No, Please vote for this Idea.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003SPjQAM